# CSS Float Styling to Place Button on Right Hand Top Side of Page

Tags: css, css-float

In below pic, Can some one suggest

I need to position Login and Register button upwards

Using Float right - am able to position buttons on right side of page

```
.discuss-main-list div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active.discussPostsList.DS06485251280568793 div#mod_improved_ajax_login-93  a.logBtn.selectBtn {      float:right }

.discuss-main-list div.tab-content div.tab-pane.active.discussPostsList.DS06485251280568793 div#mod_improved_ajax_login-93 a.regBtn.selectBtn {      float:right }
```

But how to position these buttons below the ask a question button on the red rectangular portion

Can someone suggest how to achieve same

Site

```
http://www.mycarhelpline.com/index.php?option=com_easydiscuss&view=index&category_id=0&Itemid=78
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some more of the css? Will the section above (i.e. New Cars, Finance, etc.) be a variable height? Off the top of my head, I would set the container to "position:relative" and then the buttons to "position:absolute". Then set the top and right positions on the buttons to put them in the desired location.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding your grammar.
Could you post a screen shot but edit it to show how you would like the page to look?

Comment: @sanepete - Thanks for taking time to view it. i have added a clear pic of what needs to be desired. Can you suggest in desired pls to position the login and register button at the position marked.

Comment: @ezekielDFM - More details added. Does it help to answer my query

Comment: Because of the order in the DOM you cant actually place these there without changing the DOM or using absolute positioning. Float only floats it after (or below) the previous elements, not above them.

Comment: Can you change the HTML? That's not a CSS problem, it's a HTML problem. Your div are not in the appropriate order to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste the code for the login and register buttons (just notice the style tag I added):

```html
<div id="mod_improved_ajax_login-93" style="text-align:right">
  <a href="/index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=login" onclick="return false" class="logBtn selectBtn">
    <span class="loginBtn leftBtn">
      Log in
    </span>
    <span class="loginBtn rightBtn">&nbsp;
      <img width="10" height="7" alt="\/" src="modules/mod_improved_ajax_login/themes/elegant/images/arrow.png">&nbsp;
    </span>
  </a>
  <a href="/index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=registration" class="regBtn selectBtn ">
    <span class="loginBtn leftBtn">
      Register
    </span>
    <span class="loginBtn rightBtn">&nbsp;
      <img width="10" height="7" alt="\/" src="modules/mod_improved_ajax_login/themes/elegant/images/arrow.png">&nbsp;</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In the following DOM route: div.navbar.discuss-toolbar.DS0014929228160620589.wide > div.navbar-inner > div.nav-collapse.collapse > ul.nav.pull-right, paste the buttons after the </ul> tag and before the finishing </div> tag.

You can replace style="text-align:right" with style="float:right", depending on your needs.

Hope it helps!